# Redirect a new domain name to existing website in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, domain-name, multiple-domains

I have register a new domain name (example.com.sg) without hosting server, but my existing website (example.co.uk) has hosting server with all scripts, content, and database.

How to pin point my new domain name to current website in [example.co.uk]'s htaccess file?

Or any other way to redirect that page when visitor type the URL domain name (example.com.sg) in browser and goes to my website (example.so.uk) ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're wanting to do, but if you don't have a hosting server for a domain, you will not be able to have a .htaccess file (since it would need to be hosted) and therefore would not be able to redirect in that fashion.

Like I said though, I don't really understand what you're asking.

However, a redirect from one domain to some other would look like this:

```
    Redirect 301 / http://example.co.uk/
```

That would send all hits to the root directory to example.co.uk.

Comment: Which mean I have to host my new domain name [example.com.sg] before I can add a script with the rule above by you in the [example.com.sg] folder?

Comment: Yes. .htaccess is a file. You can't store a file in a domain you don't have hosting for.

Comment: But I have .htaccess file in [example.co.uk], then i can't modify something in that .htaccess file to redirect [example.com.sg] into [example.co.uk]?

Comment: I'm very lost as to what you're trying to do and what you have on each of your domains.

Answer (score 0):

This is what `domain parking` do. Go to the cpanel of your `example.co.uk` site and select `parked domains`. Then `park example.com.sg` on `example.co.uk`